# How to build RPM of a selenium test automation project with maven?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a test automation framework with test cases. I want to build an RPM of this whole project so that it can be installed on any machine and can execute the test. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a %check scriptlet in a spec file to run the tests during a build.

Comment: can you please elaborate as I do not have any knowledge on building rpm.

Comment: There are many guides/examples (and two books) that describe how to write a spec file. E.g. see "Maximum RPM" here: http://rpm5.org/docs/max-rpm.html (the basics of writing a spec file are the same as they were in 1997 when the book was published)